# 'Duplicate these displays' not an option on older laptop running Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, laptop, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics

About a year ago, I installed Windows 10 on my Dell L502X laptop, which has Intel HD 3000 graphics.  When my laptop was running Windows 7, I could duplicate the display to an external monitor or projector; however, that no longer seems to be an option -- I can only extend the display.  I have tried the most recent Intel driver, as well as the original driver, but I have not had any success.  As another possibility, I believe the Microsoft basic display driver has limited resolution and is also unable to provide the 'Duplicate these displays' option.

Are there any ways to solve this problem?

Comment: “Are there any ways to solve this problem?” - Install the Intel Display drivers. It doesn’t appear Intel has released drivers for your iGPU.  This should work though [9.17.10.4459](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=Intel+hd+3000+windows+10). If installation of that driver does not help then there is no solution due to the fact Intel no longer supports your iGPU

Comment: @Ramhound that is the version I have installed.

Comment: You indicated you have the Microsoft Basic Display driver, the driver I suggested, is not the basic driver

Comment: I updated the question to clarify that is not the case.

Comment: https://www.tenforums.com/drivers-hardware/151105-dell-xps-l502x-intell-3000-nvidia-geforce-gt-540m-driver-errors.html

Comment: Which version of the L502X  do you have?

Comment: @Gantendo The Dell XPS15 service tag is 2ZFR3S1.  My version also has an nVIDIA Geforce GT5xxM graphics card, but my understanding is that, for laptops, graphics cards only supplement the capability of the onboard video -- they cannot replace it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing a Windows 7 partition, I finally figured out the issue with my laptop.  It has an onboard Intel HD Graphics 3000 graphics card, which apparently drives the monitor and the Mini DisplayPort.  It also has a supplemental NVIDIA GeForce GT 540M graphics chip, which drives the HDMI port.  Apparently, because of this configuration, the only way to duplicate the screen through HDMI was by using the NVIDIA Control Panel, as opposed to the Windows or Intel display settings.  To further complicate matters, it seems there was only a specific NVIDIA driver version that enabled the NVIDIA Control Panel to recognize the onboard graphics card and enable it to duplicate.  This version works on Windows 7, but not on Windows 10.

When a monitor is connected to the MDP, however, screen duplication is possible through either the Windows or Intel display settings on Windows 7 and 10.  In the past, when I would present, I would often use a MDP->VGA adapter, so I didn't have a problem.  I just ordered a MDP->HDMI adapter, which should solve the problem.  So, now I can either boot into the Windows 7 partition if I want to use the HDMI port for duplication, or I can just use a MDP adapter with Windows 10.  To further complicate matters, when I was debugging, one of my monitors seems to have a defective DisplayPort input.